# tshark job on PowerShell does not output capture file

Tags: powershell, shell, wireshark, tshark

When I run the following command in my script I expect packet_dump.pcap to get generated after I stop the script but nothing gets generated.

```
Start-Job -Name $tsharkJobName -ScriptBlock { & $tsharkPath --interface $interfaceNo -w "packet_dump.pcap" } | Out-Null
```

When I run the line below:

```
Receive-Job $tsharkJobName -Force
```

This is the error message that I get (where $interfaceNo is 5 which is the ID for Wi-Fi):

```
Capturing on 'Wi-Fi'
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Capturing on 'Wi-Fi':String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
    + PSComputerName        : localhost
```

I have this at the end of the script as well:

```
finally {
    Stop-Job $tsharkJobName
    Remove-Job $tsharkJobName -Force
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$args = "--interface " + $interfaceNo + " -w packet_dump.pcap"    
Start-Process $tsharkPath -ArgumentList $args -NoNewWindow
```

and

```
finally {
    Stop-Process -Name "tshark"
}
```

Solves this.